# how do you convert output from readLines to data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a txt file that has multiple lines. Each line as text that is separated by space. Number of columns in each line may be different. I need to read each line one at a time, put it into data frame and print it.

I tried this:

```
x<-readLines("output.txt")


for (i in 2:length(x) ) {
  data<-data.frame(x[[i]])
  print(data)
}
```

I have to start from line number 2 becasuse line number 1 has some heading info that I dont need.

For example, this prints out something like this:

```
x[[2]]
[1] "                              dcserver        AIX      2254438400       587317248   026.05   93752=100.00  HDS93752_VMAX1561_RAID1=100.00 "
```

when I do this:

```
data<-data.frame(x[[2]])
```

I get this:

```
dput(data)

structure(list(x..2.. = structure(1L, .Label = "                              dcserver        AIX      2254438400       587317248   026.05   93752=100.00  HDS93752_VMAX1561_RAID1=100.00 ", class = "factor")), .Names = "x..2..", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like I have one row and one column, I need to have 7 columns, like below:

```
dcserver        AIX      2254438400       587317248   026.05   93752=100.00  HDS93752_VMAX1561_RAID1=100.00
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of occurrences of the "number of columns in each line [being] different" you are expecting, or what the code should be able to handle?

Comment: @mkemp6, one line can have 5 columns separated by space, another line 8 etc.I need to read each line, convert to data frame and print it. I need to do this for each line in the file. The columns are separated by space, but it could be multiple spaces etc. Not consistent, so I have to account for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are better ways but I have tried this and it works for me:

```
x<-readLines("output1.txt")

for (i in 2:length(x) ) {
  x<-data.frame(x[[i]])
  writeLines(x[[i]],"test.csv")
  data<-read.csv("test.csv", header=F, sep=" ")
  df<-data[,colSums(is.na(data)) == 0]
  print(df)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the functions: `textConnection` and `read.table`.

```
x<-readLines("output.txt")

for (i in 2:length(x) ) {
  data<-read.table(textConnection(x[[i]]))
  print(data)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your original file is csv, once you readlines..

```
x=readLines("file.csv")
```

You can use read.csv

```
Df=read.csv (x)
```

Or if rather want a data.table you can use

```
Df=fread (x, sep=",")
```