# Split strings into column based on pattern

Tags: r

```
33467389|t|Immune Therapies for Hematologic Malignancies.
33467389|a|The era of immunotherapy for hematologic malignancies began with the first allogeneic hematopoietic stem cell transplant (HSCT) study published by E [...].
33477248|t|Unraveling the Role of Innate Lymphoid Cells in AcuteMyeloid Leukemia.
33477248|a|Over the past 50 years, few therapeutic advances have been made in treating.
```

This is my recurring pattern in my file.

ID which is a number for example `33467389` and the `|t|`which is the title of the paper. Similarly `33467389|a|`this denotes the abstract ID of the paper.

```
lines <- readLines("output_1/Gemtuzumab_Adult/G1.txt")
```

So im reading the file like this

So this pattern throughout my text. Is there any way to split this into columns as such

```
ID                              Abstract 
33467389      The era of immunotherapy for hematologic malignancies
```

Comment: Read the file with sep = "|", then drop 2nd column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sub` here is one base R option:

```r
df$ID <- sub("\\|.*$", "", df$text)
df$Abstract <- sub("^.*\\|", "", df$text)
df[, c("ID", "Abstract")]

        ID Abstract
1 33467389 Immune Therapies for Hematologic Malignancies.
2 33467389 The era of immunotherapy for hematologic malignancies began with the first allogeneic hematopoietic stem cell transplant (HSCT) study published by E [...].
3 33477248 Unraveling the Role of Innate Lymphoid Cells in AcuteMyeloid Leukemia.
4 33477248 Over the past 50 years, few therapeutic advances have been made in treating.
```

Comment: okay let me try it and update you

Comment: Im reading the files like this 'lines <- readLines("output_1/Gemtuzumab_Adult/G1.txt")' .from your code it seems as dataframe

Comment: @PesKchan Then read your data into a data frame first.  Most of your data manipulation should probably be happening with data frames/tables.  [See this relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899155/how-do-you-convert-output-from-readlines-to-data-frame-in-r/33964519).

Comment: okay let me see how to read character files into data frame

Answer (score 1):

Two `tidyverse` solutions:

**Data**

```
string <- data.frame(ID = "33467389|a|The era of immunotherapy for hematologic malignancies began with the first allogeneic hematopoietic stem cell transplant (HSCT) study published by E [...].")
```

**Option 1**

```
df <- string %>% 
          mutate(IDs = strsplit(ID, "\\|.*\\|")) %>%
                   tidyr::unnest_wider(IDs, names_sep = "_")
```

**Option 2**

```
string %>% 
         tidyr::separate(ID, sep = "\\|.*\\|", into = c("IDs", "Title"))
```